# Regex for matching on multiple conditions for kana + kanji

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to write a regex that match all words based on a kanji string.

For example, matching `文学生高` could return options like `文学、学生、高い,etc`

currently, I have can return only exact match on kanji entered:

`/^[学生文高]+$/` but I would like to include records that have these chars (`[ぁ-んァ-ン]`) as well.

When I try to combine the two conditions, I end up matching everything.

`/^[学生文高][ぁ-んァ-ン]+$/` <-- this is ideal, as it matches on both of those conditions.

basically, something that "must include `学生文高` but can also include `ぁ-んァ-ン` without having only including `ぁ-んァ-ン`.

For those not so familiar with Japanese, a more English example could be: searching for all words that have `test` and I would like to include numbers in results, but disallow matching just numbers.

For example, `test` match could return `test1,test2` but never just `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `/^[あ-んア-ン]*([学生文高][あ-んア-ン]*)+$/`

It matches zero or more kana at the start, then one or more groups containing one kanji and zero or more kana.

Comment: This solution works for me! Thank you for your help. You wouldn't happen to have any good resource to point to for understand `*` better? I am not 100% how this works. Wouldn't the first `[あ-んア-ン]` match any kana? or is it because of that second group `([学生文高][あ-んア-ン]*)` that it will only match kanji + kana and kanji?

Comment: It's called the "Kleene star", and it just indicated that the previous thing can be repeated zero or more times. So the first `[あ-んア-ン]` would indeed match any kana, but the `*` allows it to match zero times, so it works if there are no kana there.

Comment: I don't have a particular resource to recommend. The Wikipedia page has a section covering the [basic concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) and the fundamental [formal definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition). A little further down it covers [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) and mentioned the two main flavours or regex in use today: POSIX and Perl.